# How to exclude unwanted patterns from a set of patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching, flex-lexer, lex

I've Just started with lex programmming. The first assignment was to seperate the vowels and consonants from a file. The rule for the vowel which I wrote was- `[ aeiouAEIOU ]  {return VOWEL};` For consonants, it would be tedious to write the code - `[b-dB-D.....]` . Is there a way like `{alphabets} - {unwanted chars}`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is (in flex, not in other lex implementations):

```
[[:alpha:]]{-}[aeiouAEIOU]
```

You could also use a case-insensitive pattern:

```
(?i:[[:alpha:]]{-}[aeiou])
```

The `{-}` operator only works with character classes. It won't work with macro definitions or multicharacter subpatterns. (These will produce a syntax error when flex tries to parse the pattern.)

For more information, see the [flex manual chapter on patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).